# Как правильно собрать Maybe RxJava2?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Работаю с `Room` есть вот такой метод

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pnr = :iPnr")
abstract Maybe<UserPnrDbObject> getBy(String iPnr);
```

и есть вот такой метод

```
public Maybe<UserActivePnr> getMaybeBy(String iPnr)
{
    return getBy(iPnr)//
                      .flatMap(new Function<UserPnrDbObject, MaybeSource<UserPnrDbObject>>()
                      {
                          @Override
                          public MaybeSource<UserPnrDbObject> apply(final UserPnrDbObject iUserPnrDbObject) throws Exception
                          {
                              return concatInfoToUser(iUserPnrDbObject);
                          }
                      })//
                      .map(new Function<UserPnrDbObject, UserActivePnr>()
                      {
                          @Override
                          public UserActivePnr apply(final UserPnrDbObject iUserPnrDbObject) throws Exception
                          {
                              return PnrMapper.fromDb(iUserPnrDbObject);
                          }
                      })//
                      .flatMap(new Function<UserActivePnr, MaybeSource<UserActivePnr>>()
                      {
                          @Override
                          public MaybeSource<UserActivePnr> apply(final UserActivePnr iPnr) throws Exception
                          {
                              return Maybe.just(iPnr);
                          }
                      });
}
```

что тут должно происходить: нужно получить обьект с БД добавить к нему дополнительную информацию (метод `Maybe<UserPnrDbObject> concatInfoToUser(UserPnrDbObject iObj)`) и потом конвертировать это все из `UserPnrDbObject` в `UserActivePnr` и обернуть в `Maybe` чтоб получить в итоге `Maybe<UserActivePnr>` вот и все

Вопрос вот в чем, метод который я описал выше выполняет все эти действия и вроде бы все хорошо работает(может конечно можно как то лучше это описать?) , но если я удаляю последнюю обертку с этого метода, чтоб получилось вот так

```
public Maybe<UserActivePnr> getMaybeBy(String iPnr)
{
    return getBy(iPnr)//
                      .flatMap(new Function<UserPnrDbObject, MaybeSource<UserPnrDbObject>>()
                      {
                          @Override
                          public MaybeSource<UserPnrDbObject> apply(final UserPnrDbObject iUserPnrDbObject) throws Exception
                          {
                              return concatInfoToUser(iUserPnrDbObject);
                          }
                      })//
                      .map(new Function<UserPnrDbObject, UserActivePnr>()
                      {
                          @Override
                          public UserActivePnr apply(final UserPnrDbObject iUserPnrDbObject) throws Exception
                          {
                              return PnrMapper.fromDb(iUserPnrDbObject);
                          }
                      });
}
```

то тоже все работает...

Как так получается? Мой метод `Maybe<UserActivePnr> getMaybeBy(String iPnr)` возвращает `Maybe` , последний метод `map()` который я выполняю в цепочке должен по идее вернуть `UserActivePnr` , но он как то возвращает `Maybe<UserActivePnr>`

Что не так?

Comment: Если вопрос в том, как `map` меняет цепочку, то ответ таков - он внутри себя создаёт новый `Maybe` c типом, который возвращает `map`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб странно, что `map()` в итоге возвращает `Maybe`. Следую вашему ответу, мой первый вариант решения перегружен дополнительным `flatMap` в конце? Просто мне казалось, что именно в нем я обертываю данные в `Maybe` , получается не так?

Comment: `map` возвращает наследника `Observable` того же типа (Maybe, Single etc) который был предыдущим в цепочке вызовов. так что да - в первом варианте `flatMap` лишний. Создание нового экземпляра класса, расширяющего `Observable` происходит и в случае вызова `map` и `flatMap`. При этом конкретный тип `Observable` сохраняется.